# Error:LoginController is not abstract and does not override abstract method actionPerformed

Tags: java

Error: Error:(4, 8) java: LoginController is not abstract and does not override abstract method actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent) in java.awt.event.ActionListener

I am getting this error and I am not sure why. I have two classes View and Controller. The Controller implements ActionListner for a button that is inside the View. When a user presses a button it should run the actionPerformed method.

LoginView class

```
 import javafx.event.ActionEvent;

import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

public class LoginView extends JFrame {

    private Container container;
    private JPanel panel;
    private JButton loginButton;
    private JLabel userLabel, passwordLabel;
    private JTextField usernameField;
    private JPasswordField passwordField;

    public LoginView(){

        setTitle("Login");
        setSize(300,300);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        panel = new JPanel();
        panel.setBackground(Color.GREEN);
        add(panel);
        panel.setLayout(null);


        userLabel = new JLabel("Username:");
        userLabel.setBounds(10,20,80,25);
        userLabel.setFont(new Font("Serif", Font.PLAIN, 18));

        usernameField = new JTextField();
        usernameField.setBounds(10,40,270,40);

        passwordLabel = new JLabel("Password:");
        passwordLabel.setBounds(10,100,80,25);
        passwordLabel.setFont(new Font("Serif", Font.PLAIN, 18));

        passwordField = new JPasswordField();
        passwordField.setBounds(10,120,270,40);

        loginButton = new JButton("Login");
        loginButton.setBounds(70,190,150,60);
        loginButton.addActionListener(new LoginController());


        panel.add(userLabel);
        panel.add(usernameField);
        panel.add(passwordLabel);
        panel.add(passwordField);
        panel.add(loginButton);


        container = getContentPane();
        setVisible(true);

    }


}
```

LoginController class

```
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

public class LoginController implements ActionListener{

public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){


        }
}
```

Comment: The parameter to [`actionPerformed()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/event/ActionListener.html#actionPerformed-java.awt.event.ActionEvent-) is an **`java.awt.event.ActionEvent`**, not an `javafx.event.ActionEvent`. Your program is not a JavaFX program, so shouldn't import any `javafx` classes.

Comment: Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1):

You imported the wrong **ActionEvent** class, this is the one to import :

```
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent
```

Comment: That's not it. It was imported import java.awt.*;

Comment: I was talking about the LoginController class